# QML SplitView - manually resize childs

Tags: qt, layout, split, qml, resize

I have a QtQuick Controls 1.3 `SplitView`(as I am on QT 5.11), which contains 3 rectangles in vertical orientation. It displays fine, and I can drag-resize the childs as intended.

Now I want to add a button which allows the user to completely hide the bottom most rectangle, effectively collapsing it. However, nothing I am trying to resize the rect works:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3 as C1

[...]
    C1.SplitView  {
        id: splitView
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: parent.width - flightSelector.width - separator.width
        orientation: Qt.Vertical

        LateralChart {
            id: lateralChart
            width: parent.width
            height: mainPage.height * 0.75
            Layout.minimumHeight: 30
            Layout.maximumHeight: mainPage.height - 30 - 30
        }

        UtilityBar {
            id: utilityBar
            Layout.minimumHeight: 30
            Layout.maximumHeight: 30

            onCollapse: {
                console.log("minimize")
                flightList.height = 0                // no effect
                flightList.preferredHeight = 0       // no effect
                flightlist.Layout.maximumHeight = 0  // no effect
                flightList.shouldCollapse = true     // no effect
            }
        }

        FlightListTable {
            id: flightList
            width: parent.width
            Layout.minimumHeight: 0
            Layout.maximumHeight: mainPage.height - 60 - 30
            model: flightListFilterModel

            property bool shouldCollapse: false
            C1.SplitView.preferredHeight: shouldCollapse ? 0 : 300
        }
    }
[...]
```

If I just go `flightList.visible = false`, then the rect will be hidden, but the position of the middle rect remains, so it is positioned wrong (it should move to the bottom).

How can I resize `SplitView` child contents dynamically via JS code?

Comment: Does it help if you add `Layout.fillHeight: true` to your LateralChart?

Comment: Worked, thanks! If you add this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html#details), there must always be one (and only one) child object that has `Layout.fillheight` set to `true`. By default, it will choose the last visible child in the SplitView. In your case, it sounds like you want that to actually be the first child. So adding `Layout.fillHeight: true` to your `LateralChart` should give you the desired output.